# Dart analyzer not catching incompatible types when using null-coalescing operator

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-analyzer

I have the following code in a Flutter app that is currently running in unsound null safety mode (i.e. having both null-safe files and non-null-safe files).

```
int i = null;
String s = '';
double d = i ?? s;
```

This is obviously not correct, yet the Dart analyzer does not complain and the code compiles.

If I change the last line to

```
double d = null ?? s;
```

I get the expected error.

Shouldn't the Dart analyzer catch the error even when running in unsound null safety mode?

I have tried restarting the Dart analysis server, etc.

```
flutter doctor --verbose
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.2, on macOS 13.5.2 22G91 darwin-arm, locale en-SE)
    • Flutter version 2.10.2 at /Users/username/fvm/versions/2.10.2
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 097d3313d8 (1 year, 8 months ago), 2022-02-18 19:33:08 -0600
    • Engine revision a83ed0e5e3
    • Dart version 2.16.1
    • DevTools version 2.9.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do:

```dart
double d = i ?? s;
```

the result of `i ?? s` is the nearest common base type of `i` and `s`, which is `Object`.  `Object` then is *implicitly* downcast to `double`, which, despite being potentially unsafe, was allowed by default in the days before null-safety.

[You can disallow implicit casts by setting `strict-casts: true`](https://dart.dev/tools/analysis#enabling-additional-type-checks) (or `implicit-casts: false` prior to Dart 2.16) in your `analysis_options.yaml` file, and then you will get a static analysis error:

> error • A value of type 'Object' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'double'. • lib/foo.dart:4:14 • invalid_assignment

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the "solution". I tried setting `strict-casts: true`, which (of course) gave me hundreds - if not thousands - of errors all over the place. Most of them from stuff like `List l =jsonDecode(something)`. So not really useful to isolate the specific case of incompatible types in null coalescing operations unfortunately. Perhaps there is some lint checker that could do it?

Comment: @Magnus Since you're using an old version of Dart, you might be able to get what you want by setting `implicit-casts: false` and `implicit-dynamic: true`.  But in the long-term, it'd be best to just fix those sites to avoid using potentially unsafe implicit downcasts.